# how to call web service(.wsdl) using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I got .wsdl file from my client. by using this webservice i need validate customer information. So how to achieve this one .if customer is there or not 
xml :

```
 <xs:element name="FetchClubMembershipRequest">
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:documentation>Request to fetch customers' membership information.</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Customer_ID" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Customer_Code" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Last_Name" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="First_Name" type="xs:string" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
```

this is from wsdl.file

Answer (score 2):

In your ASP.NET project in Visual Studio, go to references, Add Service Reference, and add a reference to the live webservice that you need to call in your application. This will automatically generate all of the stub code you need to call the service.

See: [How to Consume a Web Service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/).

Comment: hi,iam able to ad the .wsdl file but i dont how to use those classess and methods inthe cs file to call this service and validate those customers passing customer Id please if you have please send me sample code  because iam new to this type of programming using webservices

Comment: @Sridhar - read the link, follow the example. try it out. if your stuck come back and tell us what your stuck with and we'll help you if we can.

Comment: actually i need to check with this .WSDL file Service is i can able to connect that Server Using this Service Or not? how to know this?Please help me how to do this Using Coding Send me the code..

Answer (score 2):

Go to Project > Add Web Reference and enter url or local path to your wsdl file and then
VS will fetch the WSDL file, and if everything is fine, it will display it on the left, and enable the Add Reference button at the bottom, so we can add it to our Project.

```
public yourWebService.xyz ws = new yourWebService.xyz();
Private void btnValidate_Click()
{
   // your webservice validation logic..
   // here m considering your webservice as checking wheather a input is number
 if(ws.checkIsNumber(txtNumber.text))
   //something if true
 else
   //something if wrong
}
```

Comment: public RSWS.CustomerWithMembership cust = new RSWS.CustomerWithMembership();
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cust.Customer_Code
     

    }what to Do i uanle to understand....please help me..iam hanged here what should i write when type Cust . iam getting string values like Customer_Code,Customer_ID ,name like please how to validate my id is existed with service database or not

Comment: please can you tell me, your webservice has methods to get customersbyID() or what all method it is giving you ??

Comment: hi,Excact ehat iam getting is. i tried one more class in that service, i am getting  this methods following is code..public RSWS.CustomerWithMembership cust=new RSWS.CustomerWithMembership();
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) iam getting object reference is not
    {
    cust.First_Name or cust.Customer_ID  thiese are all String iam getting cust.string parameters iam getting
 
    }Please Send some validation code of webservice for checking customer or not

Comment: what all methods your webservice is providing you ?

Comment: ok,i will explaine total thing what i done  i added servie reference to my application that .wsdl file(c://RSWS.wsdl) i added name space in my .cs page. and i called class  public RSWS.Customer cust=new RSWS.Customer(); later i try to check iam getting methods like Emailaddress,Addredd etc and iam getting strings values also  cust.EmailAddress.Address; if i assign that valu to another string giving error Object reference is not set to instance of the Object..basically i want to know iam able to connect that server or not Using this .wsdl web service ?.how to know iam able to connect or not ?

Answer (score 1):

Add your .wsdl address in address and click Go button.your service is add in your project.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio comes with builtin support for creating web service proxy objects from a WSDL specification. Take a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for a command-line tool that comes with Visual Studio. Most other .NET IDEs allow you to create the web service proxies 'invisibly' as well - but you'll most likely have to host the WSDL descriptor on a web site.

If you use the command line tool, you'll easily see the code generated. And if you use Visual Studio to generate the proxy instead, you can view the methods and properties of the web service proxy in the class/object browser.